# How to speed up big query in ClickHouse?

Tags: performance, clickhouse, throughput

Backgroud:

I submitted a local query in ClickHouse (without using cache), and it processed 414.43 million rows, 42.80 GB. 
The query lasted 100+ seconds. 
My ClickHouse instances were installed on AWS `c5.9xlarge` EC2 with `12T` `st1` EBS

During this query, the `IOPS` is up to `500` and read `throughput` is up to `20M/s`. 
And as a comparison, `st1` EBS max `IOPS` is `500` and max `throughput` is `500M/s`.

Here is my question:

1. Does `500` `IOPS` actually limit my query (file-reading) speed?  (never mind the cache) Should I change EBS volume type to `gp2` or `io1` to increase `IOPS`?
2. Is there any setting can improve `throughput` under the same `IOPS`? (as I can see, it's far from ceiling actually)
   I tried increasing `'max_block_size'` to read more file at one time, but it doesn't seem to work.
3. How to extend the cache time?Big query took minutes. Cache took seconds. But cache doesn't seem to last very long.
4. How can I warm-up columns to meet all requirements? Please show sqls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does 500 IOPS actually limit my query (file-reading) speed?

yes

> Should I change EBS volume type to gp2 or io1 to increase IOPS?

yes

> Is there any setting can improve throughput under the same IOPS?

tune max_bytes_to_read

reduce number of columns (in select)

reduce number of parts (in select)

> How to extend the cache time?

min_merge_bytes_to_use_direct_io=1

> How can I warm-up columns to meet all requirements? Please show sqls.

`select a,b,c,d from T Format Null`

Comment: As a reference, the table I queried contains thousands of partitions (2k for now).
I find that `max_bytes_to_read` is set to 0 by default which means no limitation. I tried to change its value, but found no significant change in performance.
Does this mean that my query produces such low throughput just because there are too many parts and it doesn't meet the `max_bytes_to_read` limit

Comment: Probably I confused `max_bytes_to_read` with another parameter. I remember that CH reads by 1MB buffer. But your goal is not throughput. Yes, 2k parts could be a reason of a pressure from 500IPS limit. Part maybe too small and CH does more IO operations to read many files instead of one. Try to rebuild the table with another partition by.